# Make session time longer on Drupal 7

Tags: configuration

I got a webform and it seems to timeout after one or two hours, I want to increase the timeout session to like 4-5 hours or more.

How do I make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

In your settings.php change/add this line

```
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', desired time in seconds);
```

it will increase your timeout length in desired way.